# WSO2 ESB 4.5.0: Unable to add server to developer studio 2.0.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When im trying to add WSO2 ESB 4.5.0 server onto developer studio im observing below error and was not letting me to add the server.

Any clues ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer Studio 2.0.1 was released couple of months prior to the release of WSO2 Carbon 4.0.0 based products.

Hence the Developer Studio 2.0.1 contains the support for the Carbon Server structure at the time of Developer Studio 2.0.1 release.

But within the time period between the release of Dev Studio 2.0.1 and Carbon 4.0 based products, there were couple changes to the structure of the Carbon Servers.

Due to these changes, you will not be able to use latest series of Carbon Servers (4.0) with Dev Studio 2.0.1.

We will fix this in the upcoming Dev Studio 2.1.0 Milestone 8.

So you will be able to use latest Carbon Servers with that version without any issue.

Note:

It seems you are trying to use WSO2 ESB 4.5.0 which is a Carbon 4.0.1 based product with Carbon 3.2.0 server category.

But you need to use Carbon 4.0.0 Category.

When you try it you will face a slightly different issue in Developer Studio 2.0.1 which is a complaint about missing lib/patches folder.

But we have fixed this for Developer Studio 2.1.0 Milestone 8.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana